# define local variable in some given scope

Tags: javascript

How could I define local variable in some given scope?

```
var f = function() {
    // (1) var localVariable = 'some value';
    alert(localVariable);
}

var defineLocalVariable = function(fnTarget) {
    // (2) fnTarget['localVariable'] = 'blah...';

    /* (3)
    with (fnTarget) {
        var localVariable = 'blah...'
    } */
}

defineLocalVariable(f);
f();
```

Look at example. If uncomment (1) code will alert value of local variable of 'f' function 'some value'. What if I want to define this local variable programmatically in runtime, is it feasible? Could you propose implementation of 'defineLocalVariable' function to define local variable in 'f', something like (2) or (3) which are not working solutions.

Thanks.

Comment: You want to inject local variables? Sounds like a bad idea, we got rid of dynamic scoping for a reason. Consider making it a parameter or part of a parameter. Explicit is better than implicit.

Comment: agree with you in general, but in my case this is really nerrow and tricky situation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Local variables are private ones. The concept of them is that they are inaccessible.

What you could do is passing it as an argument; that way, you can access it as a local variable. You should update `f`'s signature though.

```
var f = function(localVariable) {
    alert(localVariable);
}

var defineLocalVariable = function(fnTarget) {
    fnTarget(123);
}

defineLocalVariable(f);
```

but you cannot just set them for future use without calling (it seems like you want that).

Though, you could create another function that you can save, which passes a specific argument:

```
var f = function(localVariable) {
    alert(localVariable);
}

var defineLocalVariable = function(fnTarget) {
    return function() {
        fnTarget(123);
    }
}

var func = defineLocalVariable(f);
func();
```

but again, it does not modify the original function's scope directly.

Comment: can't change signature of 'f' in my situation

Comment: @Mykhaylo Adamovych: Can you neither change the body of `f`? Because then it becomes tricky if not impossible...

Comment: can't use proxy, caller will use 'f' and knows nothing about my injection

Comment: yep, can't change body of 'f'

Comment: @Mykhaylo Adamovych: Does the body contain `var localVariable`? If that's the case, I've no idea how you could ever change that value.

Comment: i know that if you try to use some variable in function, then firstly local function variable will be found, if not it will be continuing in prototypes chain. So I want to define variable in very function, but I know value of that variable only in runtime

Comment: Yep, I can define some local variable in the 'f', but I need to change it later in runtime.

Comment: @Mykhaylo Adamovych: As a last resort, you could get the function's body using `.toString()` and then modify that string somehow. After that, replace the function with the new one (`new Function(newString)`). Though that won't always work and is bound to be buggy.

Comment: Yep, I was already thinking in this way. Ugly solution :(. I wander if eval could help here...